# Extracting coordinate meshgrid from multidimensional xarray DataArray?

Tags: python-xarray

Is there a simple way to extract the values of a coordinate in the "same shape" as the DataArray? For example, from a DataArray with dimensions (**x**: 10, **y**: 12) I would like to get the x-coordinates as a 10x12 matrix instead of a 10 element long array.

I know you could do this using for example numpy's meshgrid, but I am wondering if there is a more direct and less error-prone solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xarray's [broadcast](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.broadcast.html) function is helpful here:

```
y = xr.DataArray(
    0.1 * np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),
    dims=["lat", "lon"],
    coords={"lat": np.arange(3), "lon": 10 + np.arange(4)},
    name="sst",
)

xr.broadcast(y.lon, y.lat)
```

Output:

```
(<xarray.DataArray 'lon' (lon: 4, lat: 3)>
 array([[10, 10, 10],
        [11, 11, 11],
        [12, 12, 12],
        [13, 13, 13]])
 Coordinates:
   * lon      (lon) int64 10 11 12 13
   * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2,
 <xarray.DataArray 'lat' (lon: 4, lat: 3)>
 array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]])
 Coordinates:
   * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2
   * lon      (lon) int64 10 11 12 13)
```